# Searching in more than one column

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I have an access database I search through from excel with the help of VBA and ADODB.

It works perfectly fine, but I can only search for one thing at a time. Say I want to search for all instances of "first name" in column [1] that also has "last name" in column [2]. Or, "first name" in column [1] and "address" in column [3].

How would I go about doing that from a textbox on a userform?

I was thinking of somehow adding "Firstname + Lastname" or something, but I cannot figure out the logic of the code. Any suggestions?

This is what I have for now.

```
Private Sub cmd_lookup_Click()

    Dim cn As Object
    Dim rs As Object

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set sqlConnect = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

    sqlConnect.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Source\database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

    cn.Open sqlConnect

    rs.ActiveConnection = cn

    SearchCriteria = "%" & searchCrit.Text & "%"

    rs.Open "SELECT [1],[2] ,[3],[4], [5] FROM [tblDatabase]" & _
    "WHERE      [1] LIKE '" & SearchCriteria & "' " & _
    "           OR [2] LIKE '" & SearchCriteria & "' " & _
    "           OR [3] LIKE '" & SearchCriteria & "' " & _
    "           OR [4] LIKE '" & SearchCriteria & "' " & _
    "           OR [5] LIKE '" & SearchCriteria & "' " & _
    "ORDER BY [2] Desc;", _
         cn, adOpenStatic

Dim i As Integer
If Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    i = 0
    With lstLookup
        'Code not relevant
    End With

    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing
  End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for the suggestions :)

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this. I tend to use a userform for users to input information to query. Then, save those inputs as variables. It will require some conditional logic (ie `If..End If` or `Select...Case`) in order to omit any that are blank. Kind of hard to tell you specifically without knowing the desired output.

Comment: you can build your where statement dynamically including the switching OR to AND when you want to find both.  The complication will be the gui and parameters to identify when it will be AND or OR etc.  but you could use drop down list or Checkbox for AND/OR and then just use the value when building your SQL statement

Comment: Do you have multiple input boxes on the form? If you have three boxes, for example, you can have them fill those out and then you just append an `AND` statement on the query with those values. If the boxes are blank, you can insert a wildcard instead of an empty string.

Comment: I only have one textbox and would like to keep it that way.

Comment: I think I will split the search string into an array based on the number of "+" signs in the search criteria. Then I have to figure out how to search for two different criteria in several columns at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `AND` parings separated by `OR` operators. But first have userform structured with separate text fields (and each must be a required field else you must build `WHERE` clause dynamically):

```
First Name Search:_____________
Last Name Search: _____________
Address Search: _______________
```

And then bind criteria together. Also, I would not advise numbered but named fields for debugging reasons:

```vb
rs.Open "SELECT [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]" & _
        " FROM [tblDatabase]" & _
        " WHERE ([1] LIKE '%" & FirstNameSearch & "%' " & _
        "       AND [2] LIKE '%" & LastNameSearch & "%') " & _
        " OR ([1] LIKE '%" & FirstNameSearch & "%' " & _
        "      AND [3] LIKE '%" & AddressSearch & "%') " & _
        " OR ([2] LIKE '%" & LastNameSearch & "%' " & _
        "    AND [3] LIKE '%" & AddressSearch & "%') " & _
        " ORDER BY [2] Desc;", _
        cn, adOpenStatic
```

Alternatively, use a UNION query as often in the SQL world it is discussed the efficiency between [UNION vs OR](https://www.google.com/#q=UNION+vs+OR). To be truly equivalent, a `DISTINCT` should be added to above for both to remove duplicates.

```vb
rs.Open "SELECT [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]" & _
        " FROM [tblDatabase]" & _
        " WHERE ([1] LIKE '%" & FirstNameSearch & "%' " & _
        "        AND [2] LIKE '%" & LastNameSearch & "%') " & _
        " UNION" _
        " SELECT [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]" & _
        " FROM [tblDatabase]" & _
        " WHERE ([1] LIKE '%" & FirstNameSearch & "%' " & _
        "        AND [3] LIKE '%" & AddressSearch & "%') " & _
        " UNION" _
        " SELECT [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]" & _
        " FROM [tblDatabase]" & _
        " WHERE ([2] LIKE '%" & LastNameSearch & "%' " & _
        "        AND [3] LIKE '%" & AddressSearch & "%') " & _
        " ORDER BY [2] Desc;", _
        cn, adOpenStatic
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I have named columns, I just changed the code here for practical purposes. I also only want to use one textbox. I have more than 5 columns to search in(like 25 or so) and they are everything from dates to times to names and addresses to component names etc etc. I would just like to be able to write "criteria1 + criteria2" and have SQL see if it can find the values in one of the columns and then another. Seems to be a lot more difficult than what I had hoped.